# mysqli_connect to remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote server.  I think the problem is with the port number, but when I try error reporting, I'm not getting any information.

```
$db_host        = 'MY.IP.ADD.RESS:3306';
$db_user        = 'user';
$db_pass        = 'password';
$db_database    = 'database'; 

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database) or die('Unable to establish a NHT_DB connection');


if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";
}
```

First, I'm not 100% confident that's the correct port.  How do I find out what port mysql is set to use?

Second, `mysqli_connect_error()` isn't giving me anything.  No number, codes, nothing.  The test page just spits back `Connect Error:` with out as much as a code I can go look up.

Comment: you talk to the server admins and find out, or log into the server and look at the my.ini/my.cnf files to see what it is. You've also got an `or die()` will kills the script if the connection fails, so that upon failure the mysqli_connect_error code will NEVER be reached.

Comment: took out the `or die()` and still don't get anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution was to add a port argument to the mysqli_connect function.

```
$db_host        = 'MY.IP.ADD.RESS';
$db_user        = 'user';
$db_pass        = 'password';
$db_database    = 'database'; 
$db_port        = '3306';

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database,$db_port);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can connect using mysql cli client:

```
 mysql -u db_user -h db_host -p -P 3306 db_name
```

Then, it means the httpd process doesn't have permissions to make external network connections. You can enable this by:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```