# Remote Connection to Server failed

Tags: mysql

I want to connect to a server hosted online.

My code connects to local host but when i change the values to the hosted server it gives me an error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

```
<?php

$servername = "zamokuhleWeb.co.za";
$username = "*****";
$password = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

I want to the access the database and get certain information from it

Comment: Are you able to connect to this DB using *MySQL Workbench* ? This may be some configuration to do on your DB server

Comment: That message is usually due to MySQL not being started. But in this case it could be that you are using the wrong server name, or maybe MySQL is running on a non standard port.

Comment: Or it could be a firewall issue on your or the remote server

Comment: Check the firewall on the remote server and ensure it is allowing remote MySQL connection. You may also need to ensure your connection encryption is set (or unset) correctly.

Comment: Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987746/mysql-connect-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively)

Comment: You should add a port (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575029/mysqli-connect-to-remote-server))

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Comment: OP already said that the code works if they connect to `localhost` so this is not really providing any useful information or progressing the OP to a solution