# Error: Warning: mysqli_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using xampp v 3.2.2.
I have change mysql port to 3308 and change the config.inc.php file as below:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3308';
```

I am able to open phpmyadmin.
But when I connect with the database with PHP it gives the following error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

```
<?php
     $c=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",playwithmusic);
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575029/mysqli-connect-to-remote-server)

Answer (score 1):

mySQL uses `utfmb4`, so if your client can't recognize it, then make mySQL use  `utf8 / utf8_unicode_ci`

Change the my.cnf or my.ini file to

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```