# Database connection Host is unknown

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a test database but can't seem to get the connection working. Any ideas on how I can?

**I am getting this error:**

> Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host is unknown.

```
<?php
$servername = "https://htgapi-test.azurewebsites.net/";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$db = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db );

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575029/mysqli-connect-to-remote-server)

Comment: _“Any ideas on how I can?”_ - what does the _documentation_ of your hosting service that you are using there, say about how you are supposed to connect to the database? Did it say anywhere that you are supposed to use a project-specific hostname in the first place - and not just an IP address `127.0.0.1` to access a _local_ database server?

Answer (score 0):

You have put an HTTP URL (consisting of a scheme, a server name, and a path) into the `$servername` variable.

The server name you connect to with a MySQL client needs to be **just** a server name.

In your example, the server name portion is `htgapi-test.azurewebsites.net`. Make sure that a database server is listening on the public network interface of that server.

Comment: but it is an external database

Comment: So what? You still can't connect to an HTTP endpoint with a MySQL client. That's like trying to drive a speedboat down the freeway.

Comment: sorry new to php how would i enter it then. just leave out the http and .net

Comment: No. You enter it exactly as I showed you in the last paragraph of the answer. (And this isn't a PHP issue, it's how networks work)

Comment: oh didn't see. getting a connection timeout now

Comment: Then, presumably, there isn't a database server listening on the public network interface of that server.

Comment: but if i type the link in to my browser i get a page saying that i am not permitted to view the content. so there is something right. or am i not getting it

Comment: The presence of an Internet-facing HTTP server doesn't imply the presence of any MySQL server, let alone an Internet-facing one. MySQL servers are usually heavily locked down as direct connections to them over the Internet are almost never needed and are a security risk.